# A seeming contradiction regarding the Euler characteristic of a rose

Tags: algebraic-topology

This might be really trivial, but I'm missing something that would settle the contradiction between these two facts:

(1) For $M$ a compact manifold of odd dimension $n$, $$\chi(M)=0.$$

(2) The Euler characteristic of the $n$-rose (wedge of $n$ circles) is $$\chi(\vee_n S^1)=1-n$$ since it has $1+2n$ vertices and $3n$ edges.

Isn't the $n$-rose an odd dimensional compact manifold, and should thus have $\chi=0$? What property of the $n$-rose am I missing, that would mean that theorem (1) doesn't apply to it?

Comment: It's not a manifold. Hint: What happens if you remove the gluing point? How many components does the rose split into? Compare that with a manifold.

Comment: @ThePuix You're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is a simpler CW structure on the $n$-rose so that it has $1$ vertex and $n$ edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ThePuix points out in their comment, this rose is *not* a manifold for $n > 1$ since the wedge point doesn't have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Note that when $n=1$ the rose is just a circle and so it is a manifold, and your formula confirms that $\chi(\vee_1 S^1) = 0$.

You also need to be careful with your first assertion: it's **not true** that $\chi(M)=0$ for every compact odd-dimensional manifold, for example $\chi(D^k) = 1$ for all $k$. However if the manifold is **closed** (compact and without boundary) then $\chi(M) = 0$ is a consequence of Poincare duality.